# How to specifiy a column min-width?

Tags: datatables

How can I specify a `min-width` for a column in DataTables?

I can't use a class with [`className`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) because the width is variable. The `width` option isn't sufficient. There doesn't appear to be a `style` option.

Comment: So you want to assign `min-width` at runtime, and don't want to use class(es) with pre-defied min-width, correct?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com That's right. I don't want to create hundreds of CSS classes for every individual column on every individual page.

Answer (score 10):

I would still recommend to use a class name or multiple class names and [`columns.className`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) option to keep CSS rules where they belong - in CSS files.

However if you want to assign `min-width` value at run-time, you can use [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) option to define a callback for whenever a `TR` element is created for the table's body.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'createdRow': function(row, data, dataIndex){
      $('td:eq(3)', row).css('min-width', '200px');
   }
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/g3jxow5b/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Isn't there a better callback than `createdRow`? Really it only needs to run once on the headers.

Comment: @mpen, I agree it needs to be done once in the header, and you can use `initComplete` and target `th` element. However in certain cases (for example, vertical scrolling) DataTables creates separate table just for headers so setting `min-width` on header will break the layout and will require special handling. Solution above is universal.